# Autowiring factory bean

Tags: spring

I have 2 beans "myBeanA" and "myBeanB". I have to return one of them on start-up according to some flag.

I decided to implement this with a factory

```
<bean id="myBeanFactory" class="MyBeanFactory"/>
<bean id="myBeanA" class="MyClassImplA"/>
<bean id="myBeanB" class="MyClassImplB"/>
<bean id="myBean" class="MyInterface" bean-factory="myBeanFactory" bean-method="getMyBean"/>
```

Now the factory should do something like this

```
public MyInterface getMyBean(){
    if ( flag ) { 
           return (MyInterface) context.getBean("myBeanA");
    }else{
           return (MyInterface) context.getBean("myBeanB");
    }
}
```

This works fine.. but when I try to inject "myBeanB" and "myBeanA" into myBeanFactory, I get nulls..

```
@Inject  // assume setters included.. 
private MyInterface myBeanA;

@Inject // assume setters included...
private MyInterface myBeanB;

public MyInterface getMyBean(){
   return flag ? myBeanA : myBeanB;
}
```

For some reason in this case - myBeanA and myBeanB are both null!

How do I get this to work?

Comment: based on what `flag` value set?

Comment: It varies. Sometimes it is a system property, sometimes it is if a server is reachable. Shouldn't affect the answer

Comment: I am not sure there's enough information to answer that.

Comment: @P.Lalonde - please let me know what is missing, and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Awtowired` annotation instead. To use `@Inject` annotation you have to have a special jar on claspath that supports it. Also you have to have
`<context:annotation-config/>` element in your xml to enable awtowiring. Also you should enable autowiring by name for those 3 beans(myBean, myBeanA, myBeanB).

Comment: Yes, sure. But also you have to set autowire type by name in bean definitoin